# How to align UIBarButtonItems properly on iOS 13 on iPad?

Tags: ios, alignment, uinavigationbar

Since iOS 13 some of my navigation controllers look broken. I use nothing special just a plain old `UINavigationController` and some storyboard added bar button items in it. Since iOS 13 the buttons stick to the edges of the modal window instead of keeping the margins distance. Any ideas how to fix it?

[image: UINavigationBar with wrong layout]